# When is the HtmlRowPreparedEvent fired on the ASPxDataGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, devexpress

I am using the DevExpress ASPxDataGrid in one of my projects. I notice that there is an event called HtmlRowPrepared that can be used to conditionally style a given row.

What I would like to know is when is this event fired?

Is it when I databind to the control or should I raise the event myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This event is actually raised by the grid automatically when the control is rendered.  Due to the ASP.NET Page Life cycle, the grid is rendered twice during a single request:

1) when the controls hierarchy is created for the first time to restore the previous control state
2) when the controls hierarchy is created to render the resulting control

So, definitely, you should not try to raise it, the grid will do this itself when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

`ASPxDataGrid.HtmlRowPrepared` event will be raised automatically so you you don't need to rise it by yourself.